# ¿Cómo restablecer el valor original de un mat input si se borra su contenido?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo una tabla con el campo **Descripcion** el cual es editable, ahorita valida que si se ingresan más caracteres del máximo  permitido muestra un mensaje de error, pero lo que quiero validar es que si el usuario borrra todo se vuelva a restablecer su valor original que trae del servicio, es decir, que no permita que se elimine todo del input, sino que solo se pueda modificar lo que se muestra, pero no se como volverle a setear el valor y que cuando se borre su contenido en automatico aparezca el valor que tenia, o cuando se le de click en el boton actualizar y entre al método actualizar, se restablezca ahi el valor

HTML

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
                    <div class="scrollme">
                        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceGpoProd" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID  </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcion">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DESCRIPCIÓN </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
                                        <input matInput type="text" [value]="element.descripcion"
                                            (keyup)="valorDescripcion($event.target,element)"
                                            [disabled]="!element.edit">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                    <br>
                                    <span class="error" *ngIf="element.limiteExcedido">El tamaño máximo para este campo
                                        es
                                        de 20</span>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="botonGpoActions">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ACCIONES </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
                                    <button mat-icon-button color="primary"
                                        (click)="actualizar(element,productoModel)"
                                        matTooltip="Editar registro">
                                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                                    </button>
                                    <button mat-icon-button color="warn"
                                        (click)="eliminar($event.target,element)"
                                        matTooltip="Eliminar registro">
                                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>

                            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsSubtipoProd"></tr>
                            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsSubtipoProd">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <mat-paginator #paginatorSubtipo="matPaginator" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="10"
                        [pageSizeOptions]="[10]" showFirstLastButtons>
                    </mat-paginator>
                </mat-expansion-panel>
```

component.ts

**UPDATE:**

```
dataSourceProd: any;
  obtenerProd() {
    this.productService.obtenerProducto().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.data.length == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          text: 'Sin datos para mostrar'
        })
      } else {
        this.tipoProducto = response.data;
        console.log("DATA    ",this.tipoProducto);
        this.dataSourceProd = new MatTableDataSource(this.tipoProducto);
        this.dataSourceProd.paginator = this.paginatorTipo;
      }

    });
  }
  
 
 valorDescripcion(e: any, row: any) {
    this.idSelecc = row.id;
    this.subDescripcion = e.value;
    if (this.subDescripcion.length > 20) {
      row.limiteExcedido = true;
    } else {
      row.limiteExcedido = false;
    }
  }

actualizar(element: any, productoModel: GpoProducto) {
    if (element.edit) {
      element.edit = false;
      if (this.subDescripcion == null) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Error',
          text: 'No hay registros modificados'
        });
      } else {
        
        if(this.subDescripcion == 0){
          console.log("DESCRIPCION VACIA");
         
         Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Error',
            text: 'Error en la operación, no puedes eliminar el valor descripcion'
          });
            //Recupero el valor de la DATA que me regresa el servicio y le paso el ID
           this.subDescripcion = this.tipoProducto[this.idSelecc].descripcion;
        
        }else{
            productoModel.id = this.idSelecc;
            productoModel.descripcion = this.subDescripcion;
            this.productService.actualizarService(productoModel).subscribe(data => {
                productoModel = data;
                this.tipoProductoDesc = null;
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Éxito',
                    text: 'Registro actualizado correctamente'
                });
            });
        }
        
      }

    } else {
      element.edit = true;
    }
  }
```

En el metodo **actualizar** agrego la validacion de cuando el valor del campo **descripcion** esta vacio y mando un mensaje de error, pero cuando le doy  click en el boton de OK del mensaje quiero que vuelva a aparecer el valor que tenia antes, y por eso le seteo el valor del servicio, pero no muestra nada

Comment: La validación que estas buscando primero es que no este vacío ese campo, para eso hay muchos ejemplos en la documentación.

Comment: @René modifiqué como agregué la validacion dentro del método actualizar, y ya me manda un mensaje de que no puedes borrar el valor, pero cuando le seteo el valor que traigo del servicio, no muestra nada